# Jquery events for ajax post after DOM is loaded

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm having trouble getting post DOM created elements to inherit jquery events. 
As I understand it, on() should take care of this - but I can't get it working for elements created inside my form-sumbit 'post' call.
I have also tried: $("form").on("sumbit",function() {

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('p.dev_summary').on("click",function() {
        $(this).next().toggle();
        }); 

    $("form").submit(function() {
    var dev_text = $('textarea').attr('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "composite/submit_dev",
            data: "dev_text=test",
            success: function(){
                var $content = $('<div class=insert_dev id></div><p class=dev_summary>Some Text</p>');
                $content.insertBefore( $('div.insert_dev');
            }
        });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Thank you in advance.

HTML/PHP as requested (codeigniter):

```
<div class="composite_wrapper">
<?php foreach($development as $row): ?>
<div class="insert_dev" id="<?php echo $row['orderid'];?>"></div>
<p class="dev_summary"><?php echo 'Summary: ' .$row['text'];?></p>
<div class="development"><?php echo $row['text']?></div>
<?php endforeach ?>

<?php 
$attributes = array('style' => 'display: none');

?>
<?php echo form_open('#',$attributes); ?>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<p>
<label for="dev_text">Development:</label>
<br />
<?php echo form_textarea('dev_text'); ?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 implementations of on(). One allows binding directly to elements but those elemnts must exist, and does not account for futures.

The other method is a delegation method. You delegate the handler to a higher level elementt or the document. This method catches the event as it bubbles

```
 $(document).on('click', 'p.dev_summary', function ......
```

Look at optional selector in on() docs

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good detailed read for how jQuery handled these event handlers:

http://www.elijahmanor.com/2012/02/differences-between-jquery-bind-vs-live.html

Like the above poster said, you are using the on selector in the way of handling for the bind handler. But you should be using it for delegate or live.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to try bind:

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: You may use something like this:

    document.createElement(element).bind('click', function() { //... });

Comment: not for future elements..that's why live() was created... and now superseded by on(). Currently bind() uses on() in jquery core

Comment: Oh, thank you for the insight. Might have some code to change if this is the case...

Comment: np..that's what this place is all about